# I want to get the values of the rows in excel using laravel but it keeps repeating

Tags: excel, laravel, for-loop, foreach

I imported excel on my laravel application and I extracted the data which I want to loop through row and get the values. I am getting the values but it keeps repeating

```
public function bulkTransfer(Request $request)
{
    Log::info("########## Validating File #########");

    $request->validate([
        "file" => 'required|file|mimes:csv,xlsx'
    ],[
        "fileName.mimes" => "File should be a csv or excel file"
    ]);
    Log::info("########## File Validated #########");

    if($request->has("file")){
        $allAccounts = Excel::toArray(new \stdClass(), $request->file("file"));
        foreach ($allAccounts as $accounts){
            foreach ($accounts as $account){
              for ($i=0; $i<=count($account); $i++){
                  echo '<p>'.  $account[1] . " " . $account[2] . " " . $account[3] . "</p>";
              }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The is the array of data that I got from the excel file

```
array:1 [ // app/Http/Controllers/TransferController.php:33
  0 => array:4 [
    0 => array:4 [
      0 => "Account Name"
      1 => "Account Number"
      2 => "Bank Code"
      3 => "Amount"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      0 => "Okafor John"
      1 => 98393
      2 => 988
      3 => 3000
    ]
    2 => array:4 [
      0 => "Joy Ema"
      1 => 87383
      2 => 8378
      3 => 2000
    ]
    3 => array:4 [
      0 => "Ike Sam"
      1 => 89382
      2 => 888
      3 => 1500
    ]
  ]
]
```

When I run my code this is the output that I get

Account Number Bank Code Amount

Account Number Bank Code Amount

Account Number Bank Code Amount

Account Number Bank Code Amount

Account Number Bank Code Amount

98393 988 3000

98393 988 3000

98393 988 3000

98393 988 3000

98393 988 3000

87383 8378 2000

87383 8378 2000

87383 8378 2000

87383 8378 2000

87383 8378 2000

89382 888 1500

89382 888 1500

89382 888 1500

89382 888 1500

89382 888 1500

Comment: hi, i think ` for ($i=0; $i<=count($account); $i++){` no need, delete it and chack again

Comment: $account is an array. I can't echo $account

Comment: send answer, and write simple code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can show item like this:

```php
      if ($request->has("file")) {
        $allAccounts = Excel::toArray(new \stdClass(), $request->file("file"));
        foreach ($allAccounts as $accounts) {
            foreach ($accounts as $account) {

                //your code : 
                echo '<p>' . $account[1] . " " . $account[2] . " " . $account[3] . "</p>";

                // better way
                echo sprintf('<p> %s %s %s %s </p>', $account[0], $account[1], $account[2], $account[3]);

                // php 8.2
                echo sprintf('<p> %s %s %s %s </p>', ...$account);
            }

        }
    }
```

check this code